# Python Pandas df.min() returns inf

Tags: python, excel, pandas

I have been working on a Python code to take data from a CSV file and paste it to a new Excel document. I am using Python 2.7, Numpy and Pandas.

I am able to:

- read the CSV file
- Isolate the column I'm interested in
- Write to a new Excel file

I am unable to:

- find the minimum value within that isolated column

What I tried:

- Google
- Trying to replace inf to NaN and remove

I added the following lines after the:

```
print(DTFRL.min())
```

line of code

```
DTFRL.replace([np.inf, -np.inf], np.nan)
DTFRL.replace([np.inf, -np.inf], np.nan).dropna(subset=["col1", "col2"], how="all")
```

My code without the above addition is as follows:

```
# James Hayek
# Takes input from a CSV file and exports the data to
# an Excel document

# Goals:
#   1. Import the highest or lowest value in CSV file
#   2. Place the value in a specific column in an Excel file
#   3. Incriment through a slew of CSV files
#   4. Open all CSV files from a file path that the user picks

import numpy as np
import pandas as pd
pd.set_option('display.mpl_style', 'default') # Make the graphs a bit prettier. See warning, change later

#This line reads the entire data set from the CSV file
DTFRL_df = pd.read_csv('C:\\Users\\James\\OneDrive\\Documents\\cSquared\\ExcelPythonAutomation\\CSVFiles\\31-SPT76-ANT123-DTF.csv', sep=',', error_bad_lines=False)
DTFRL = DTFRL_df.iloc[0:1100,1] #Setting a variable for the DTF-RL column

#print(DTFRL_df.iloc[0:1100,1]) #This prints all the rows and just the second column

print(DTFRL.min()) #Atempting to print the lowest value in the second column, but getting inf instead

DTFRL.replace([np.inf, -np.inf], np.nan)
DTFRL.replace([np.inf, -np.inf], np.nan).dropna(subset=["col1", "col2"], how="all")

#This line writes the variable DTRFL_df to a new Excel file, can change variable to write later
#to make sure we just write the lowest value found 
DTFRL.min().to_excel('C:\\Users\\James\\OneDrive\\Documents\\cSquared\\ExcelPythonAutomation\\test.xlsx')
```

My Question:

- What do I need to specify in .dropna(subset=["?", "?"]) to irradicate the inf value returned as oposed to the lowest float?

Thanks in advance for the help

Here is the head of the CSV file to reproduce the issue.

```
Title,SubTitle,
DTF-RL,,
Parameter Name,Setting,
Resolution:,1033,
CAL:,On (OSL-Std),
RF Immunity:,High,
Std:,None,
Freq: Start/Stop:,698.0 MHz/2700.0 MHz,
Date:,"Thursday, December 17, 2015",
Time:,8:08:26 PM,
Ins. Loss:,0.045 dB/ft,
Model:,S331L,
Serial:,1307024,
Prop.Vel:,0.865,
Marker Data,,
Marker,Distance( ft),Value
M1,85.63468992,-1.017566517
Limit On,Value: 25.00,
Point Data,,
Distance( ft),DTF-RL,
0,43.37040226,
0.121124031,41.60694628,
0.242248062,42.73552301,
0.363372093,49.25223571,
0.484496124,65.76120197,
0.605620155,71.70100065,
0.726744186,68.81150462,
```

The file can be accessed [here](https://drive.google.com/open?id=0BxNGritBJp1zTV9MX3U1bngyWUE).

Comment: Numerical data starts at line 21. Will you do anything with the string data? If not, you can just use the `skiprows` parameter.

Answer (score 2):

you can filter non numeric number using [isnumeric()](http://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/version/0.17.0/generated/pandas.Series.str.isnumeric.html)

```
import csv
import pandas as pd
from io import StringIO

data = "out.txt"
df = pd.read_csv(data,header=0,encoding ='utf-8')
print df
df_out= df[df.id.apply(lambda x: x.isnumeric())]
print df_out
```

out.txt

```
id,name
1,A
2,B
3,C
tt,D
4,E
5,F
de,G
```

creates the output

```
  id name
0  1    A
1  2    B
2  3    C
4  4    E
5  5    F
```

Comment: change 'id' to  the column name that you are interested from from your data frame.df[df.'Columnnamefromdf'.apply(lambda x: x.isnumeric())]

Comment: This doesn't return the lowest value in the second colomn. I modified your code like so: "DTFRL_df_out= DTFRL_df[DTFRL_df.Title.apply(lambda x: x.isnumeric())]
print DTFRL_df_out" The output is giving me two lines, it should just be one. The output is:                                                                                       Title     SubTitle Unnamed: 2
19       0  43.37040226        NaN
1051   125  70.91996079        NaN

Comment: I just realized that and removed my comment. When I use the title "Title" I get back what I posed in the comment above, when I put SubTitle in place of ID I get te following error messege:  AttributeError: 'float' object has no attribute 'isnumeric'

Comment: You can't call `isnumeric()` on a numeric type--only on strings. make sure you read the column in as a string before checking if the elements are numeric or not.

Comment: @3novak That makes sense... I converted it to a string as such: "DTFRL_df = str(DTFRL_df)" which was placed after the pd.read command. I am getting an error of "'str' object has no attribute 'SubTitle'" now

Comment: df = pd.read_csv(data,header=0,encoding ='utf-8',converters ={'SubTitle':str}) use this instead of str(DTFRL_df)"